# CSS bottom Border Issue

Tags: css

I seem to be having issues with the either the border, or the box shadow appearing on my site.

If need be I will post the CSS for the areas that have the borders applied but it may be easier to just link you to my site: http://w11.zetaboards.com/GamesAndAnime/index/

Comment: Please share more details...

Comment: Please, specify where your having the issues with.

Comment: It's a bit hard to explain, which is why I linked you to the site.
If you look at the bottoms of the td, c_mark, etc then you will notice that the glow effect I have on everything doesn't apply to the bottoms of them.

Notice in this screenshot how the bottom of it is different: http://prntscr.com/3dmzsf

Answer (score 0):

Please remove below tr

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="6" class="c_foot"></td>
</tr>
```

And add padding-bottom:10px to table (css.css line no:31) like below

```
table {
clear: both;
width: 100%;
padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```